# Prediction and explanation of user rating based on multiple criteria

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, predictive-models, recommender-system

I'm trying to figure out a way to both predict how a user would rate a certain document, as well as an explanation of why certain documents are rated a certain way.

A user is represented by:

- favorite topics;
- average length of the documents the user read;
- the distribution of the times of day a user reads the documents;
- location;
- age.

With this information I want to:

1. Predict how much a user will like a document (based on the document's topics, length, the time of day, etc)
2. Get explanations like: documents with this length are usually read around this time; or, documents about these topics are usually read at these locations.

I hope this question is not too broad. I just need some starting tips.

Comment: Please describe the nature of your "rating" variable:  is it Good/Bad, or on a scale from 0-10 or A-F, or something else?

Comment: @rolando2 A numerical scale [0-10] will do.

Answer (score 1):

Since (per your comment) you have a rating from 1 to 10, I think the first thing to try is ordinal logistic regression. Another possibility that I have been reading about is beta regression, but this will be less familiar to nearly everyone (although, from what I'm reading, it looks much more flexible).

Comment: What if I was just looking to predict a good/bad rating?

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to lump things like that, but if you wanted to, you could create a new variable GOODRATE with values 0 and 1 and then use regular logistic

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Flom suggests, logistic regression would be a good place to start.

If your goal is automated prediction more than an easily interpretable model, you might want to read through the [solutions thread](http://www.kaggle.com/c/event-recommendation-engine-challenge/forums/t/3894/solutions) for Kaggle's Event Recommendation Engine contest. That was focused on a binary interested/not outcome, but otherwise has some similarities to your problem.